# Pacemaker 2 floatingIP

Tags: high-availability, pacemaker

I'm triying to config a cluster with two servers, each of them with two interfaces, and i want to config two floatings ips, one private and other public.
The idea is, if some of two interface fail in one server fails, cluster swicths to the other server.

I'm using pacemaker but until now, i've just made it work with one floating IP. With two, until now, no way.
I'm configuring two resources (2 float ip) and two rings.

Have somebody tried this? Or somebody can guide me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Should be fairly simple. Just configure up another IPaddr2 primitive. If you need to specify which interface the virtual IP binds to this can be done fairly easily via the `nic=` parameter. Naturally, the interface names on both nodes will need to match if using `nic=` parameter. for example:

```
primitive p_ip_private IPaddr2 \
    params ip=192.168.35.5 cidr_netmask=255.255.255.0 nic=eth1 \
    op start interval=0 timeout=20 \
    op stop interval=0 timeout=20s \
    op monitor interval=20 timeout=20
```

You need not use the `nic=` parameter though. The IPaddr2 resource agent should be smart enough to properly choose the right interface based upon the network and subnet already assigned to the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer. I've just tried that without success.
I've created two floating IPs like this:

pcs resource create publicIP ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 ip=10.0.0.110 cidr_netmask=32 nic=enp0s3 op monitor interval=30s

pcs resource create privateIP ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 ip=192.168.123.110 cidr_netmask=32 nic=enp0s8 op monitor interval=30s

In my servers, i have two network interfaces in the same ranges above.
So, when i stop one interface enp0s3 cluster move the resources to the other server. But if i stop enp0s8 nothing happen.
The great situation would be moving resources if any network interface fail.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For doing that you should create a monitor resource IP address, like

if ping fails all resources go to node X